# How can I make my floor handle a 3500 lb. aquarium?

Tags: floor, joists, support, load

I want to put a 220 gallon aquarium along an outside wall over an 8 foot sliding door. Across from there is a set of stairs.

The floor joists are 2"x10"x15' at 16" on center with two layers of 3/4" OSB on top. The house was built in 1963 and was remodeled 1 year ago.

Will the 8 foot door hold the weight and will the joist that ties to the stair right across from door hold the weight?

Let’s say tank is 3500lbs and 6 feet by 2 feet. That's 292 lbs of weight per square foot of floor that is moving because of water movement.

Comment: The weight isn't moving much, unless this is a wave tank; I think you can treat that as a static load.

Comment: Would be concerned about putting that much weight over a door header that might not made for that extra weight.

Comment: 220 gallons x 8 pounds/gallon = 1760 pounds. Add to that the weight of the tank itself, plus a stand, fish, and whatever other accoutrements you have. Does all the rest add up to 1300 pounds to get to your 3500 pound estimate? Where does the "292lbs of weight moving" come from?

Comment: Do your floor joists run perpendicular to the sliding door opening, so that the tank would straddle several joists?

Comment: North of the border 220 gallons of water will weigh 2200 Lbs.  Makes math simple.  Do think that over estimating the weight is good for supports needed.

Comment: You haven't said what the door header is. That's critical here, as is the overall floor system layout. More information, please.

Comment: @FreeMan The fish don't actually add any weight to the aquarium, as they displace their volume of water so you have to put less water in. Plus they are generally neutrally buoyant, so weigh the same as the water they displace.

Comment: You (OP) calculated a static live load of 292 lbs per sq ft.  The usual design live load for a residential floor is 40 lbs/sq ft.  So the aquarium tank presents a load that's 7.3 times greater than the design (and probably built to) standard. Now I know the entire floor doesn't see this load - it's more like a step function.  But I think this calls for a structural engineer's assessment, or at a minimum a load calculation done on your actual floor load with the aquarium tank.

Comment: @Glen Yates - That's not true where the water volume is constrained as in this tank, unless adding the fish causes the tank to lose water.

Answer (score 3):

The weight isn't moving much, unless this is a wave tank; I think you can treat that as a static load.

But given the size of that load, I think the real answer to your question may be "hire an engineer to evaluate this", since the question involves details of construction and load distribution. You may be advised to replace the current header of that door with a beam, and there may be other changes considered advisable.

I may be being overcautious. I haven't computed what the weight of a loaded bookcase with that footprint would be. But if you're nervous enough to ask, buying some certainty seems worthwhile

Comment: Another option may be to get a general contractor to come out, look at it, and tell you whether you need an engineer's opinion. If they say you don't, you'll save money. But if they say you do, you're now paying both of them. Your call.

Comment: The sistered 2x8's as a beam sounds like it might be in the right ballpark; I have a passageway in a hopefully-nonloadbearing[*] wall that's supported by a 4x10 parallam beam and when we took out a section of structural wall I think they went with 4x12 parallam plus a similar kind of manufactured lumber for the supports plus sistering an iron C-beam to one of the floor joists under this to transfer load from middle of the house to the foundation.   [*In an older building, what is and isn't bearing load may not be what the designers intended.]